Jquery DevExpress Datagrid with remote paging & local grouping in laravel backpack crud controller
I used Devexpress Datagrid in php laravel blade template use override default list view of laravel backpack crud controller. as devexpress as more controller then list view of backpack which is in datatables. specifically for grouoing i choose that. So for local data it is working by getting all the data from server with grouping. but grouping is doing so much odd things when paging and other stuff is remote but grouping is local. When grouping any thing is grouped that ok but on expanding or collapsing it s getting wrong pages count with working skip take which make server side too odd to difficult to get correct page details
here is devexpress config of jquery
<script>
    const config = {
        noDataText: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.emptyTable') }}",
        columnMinWidth: 50,
        searchPanel: {
            visible: false,
            highlightSearchText: false,
        },
        remoteOperations: {
            sorting: true,
            filtering: true,
            paging: true,
            grouping: false,
            groupPaging: false,
        },
        columnAutoWidth: true,
        onRowPrepared: function(e) {
            if (e.rowType == "data") {
                e.rowElement.find(".dx-datagrid-group-closed").append(
                    "<i class='fa fa-plus-square-o' aria-hidden='true''></i>")
                e.rowElement.find(".dx-datagrid-group-opened").append(
                    "<i class='fa fa-minus-square-o' aria-hidden='true''></i>")
            }
        },
        masterDetail: {
            enabled: "{{ $crud->details_row }}",
            template: function(container, options) {
                var rowId = options.data.DT_RowId;
                $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ url($crud->route) }}/' + rowId + '/details',
                        type: 'GET',
                    })
                    .done(async function(data) {
                        container.append("<div class='table_row_slider shown'>" + data + "</div>")
                    })
            },
        },
        dataSource: {
            load: function(loadOptions) {
                console.log(loadOptions)
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                const gridState = setGridState(loadOptions)
                const paramsObject = {
                    ...[...(new URLSearchParams((new URL(window.crud.url)).search))].reduceRight((acc, [
                        key, value
                    ]) => {
                        if (key.includes('[')) {
                            let keys = key.split(/[[\]]{1,2}/).filter(x => x);

                            function assignValue(obj, keys, value) {
                                let key = keys[0];
                                if (keys.length === 1) {
                                    if (key === "") {
                                        obj.push(value);
                                    } else {
                                        obj[key] = value;
                                    }
                                    return;
                                } else {
                                    if (key === "") {
                                        key = obj.length;
                                    }
                                    if (!obj[key]) {
                                        obj[key] = (keys[1] === "") ? [] : {};
                                    }
                                    return assignValue(obj[key], keys.slice(1), value);
                                }
                            }
                            assignValue(acc, keys, value);
                        } else {
                            acc[key] = value;
                        }
                        return acc;
                    }, {}),
                    ...gridState
                }
                const queryString = $.param(paramsObject)
                const uniqueQueryString = Array.from(new Set(queryString.split('&').reverse())).reverse()
                    .join('&')
                window.crud.url = new URL(window.crud.url).origin + new URL(window.crud.url).pathname +
                    '?' +
                    uniqueQueryString

                if (loadOptions.url) {
                    window.crud.url = loadOptions.url
                    window.crud.table.getDataSource().reload()
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: window.crud.url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        crudTableId: 'crudTable',
                    },


                    success: (result) => {
                        deferred.resolve({
                            data: result.data,
                            totalCount: totalCount,
                        });
                    },
                    fail: (error) => {}
                });
                return deferred.promise();
            }
        },

        onRowExpanding: function(e) {


            // Get all groups
            var groups = window.crud.table.getVisibleRows().filter(row => row.rowType === "group");

            // Loop through all groups and collapse those which are not the one being expanded
            groups.forEach(group => {
                if (group.key !== e.key) {
                    window.crud.table.collapseRow(group.key);
                }
            });
        },
        keyExpr: "DT_RowId",
        filterRow: {
            visible: false
        },
        groupPanel: {
            visible: false,
        },
        grouping: {
            allowCollapsing: true,
        },
        allowColumnResizing: true,
        columnResizingMode: 'widget',
        columns: columns,
        showBorders: true,
        paging: {
            pageSize: {{ $crud->getDefaultPageLength() }},
        },
        pager: {
            visible: true,
            allowedPageSizes: @json($crud->getPageLengthMenu()[0] ?? []),
            showPageSizeSelector: true,
            showInfo: true,
            showNavigationButtons: true,

        },
        onCellPrepared: "{{ $crud->hasAccess('show') }}" == true ? function(e) {
            let skipIndexes = -1
            if (bulkAllowed) {
                skipIndexes++;
            }
            if (e.column && e.column.index < columns.length - 1 && e.key && e.key.DT_RowId) {
                if (e.column.index > skipIndexes) {
                    e.cellElement.css("cursor", "pointer");
                    e.cellElement.click((event) => {
                        window.location.href = "{{ url($crud->route) }}/" + e.key
                            .DT_RowId ?? "";
                    })
                }
            }
        } : undefined,
        customizeColumns(columns) {
            columns.forEach((column, index) => {
                if (column.allowGrouping) {
                    column.groupCellTemplate = function(container, options) {
                        const columnValue = getTextOfHTML(options.value);
                        container.append(
                            `<p style="font-weight:bold; display:flex; align-items:center; width: 100%; margin:0 !important">${options.column.caption} : ${columnValue} <span style="font-weight:bold; margin-left:auto;">
                                    </span><p>`
                            // ${options.data && options.data.items ? options.data.items.length ?? 0 : 0}
                        );
                    };
                }
                column.cellTemplate = function(container, options) {
                    container.append(options.value);
                    if (index === columns.length - 1) {
                        container.css("overflow",
                            "visible");
                    }
                };
            });
        },
        onContentReady: function(e) {
            crud.functionsToRunOnDataGridDrawEvent.forEach(function(functionName) {
                crud.executeFunctionByName(functionName, [crud]);
            });
            $('.dx-datagrid-table td span[class*="details-control"]').remove()

            var gridInstance = e.component;
            // Collapse all groups once the content is ready
            var groups = gridInstance.getVisibleRows().filter(row => row.rowType === "group");
            if (!window.crud.isInitialized) {
                groups.forEach((group, i) => {
                    gridInstance.collapseRow(group.key);
                    console.log(groups[groups.length - 1], i)
                    if (groups.length - 1 == i) {
                        window.crud.isInitialized = true
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<?php

namespace Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations;

trait ListOperation
{
    /**
     * Display all rows in the database for this entity.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('list');
        $this->crud->setOperation('list');

        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->crud->getTitle() ?? mb_ucfirst($this->crud->entity_name_plural);

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getListView(), $this->data);
    }

    /**
     * The search function that is called by the data table.
     *
     * @return array JSON Array of cells in HTML form.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('list');
        $this->crud->setOperation('list');

        $totalRows = $this->crud->model->count();
        $filteredRows = $this->crud->count();
        $startIndex = $this->request->input('start') ?: 0;
        // if a search term was present
        if ($this->request->input('search') && $this->request->input('search')['value']) {
            // filter the results accordingly
            $this->crud->applySearchTerm($this->request->input('search')['value']);
            // recalculate the number of filtered rows
            $filteredRows = $this->crud->count();
        }
        // start the results according to the datatables pagination
        if ($this->request->input('start')) {
            $this->crud->skip((int) $this->request->input('start'));
        }
        // limit the number of results according to the datatables pagination
        if ($this->request->input('length')) {
            $this->crud->take((int) $this->request->input('length'));
        }
        // overwrite any order set in the setup() method with the datatables order
        if ($this->request->input('order')) {
            $column_number = $this->request->input('order')[0]['column'];
            $column_direction = $this->request->input('order')[0]['dir'];
            $column = $this->crud->findColumnById($column_number);
            if ($column['tableColumn']) {
                // clear any past orderBy rules
                $this->crud->query->getQuery()->orders = null;
                // apply the current orderBy rules
                $this->crud->query->orderBy($column['name'], $column_direction);
            }

            // check for custom order logic in the column definition
            if (isset($column['orderLogic'])) {
                $this->crud->customOrderBy($column, $column_direction);
            }
        }
        $entries = $this->crud->getEntries();

        return $this->crud->getEntriesAsJsonForDatatables($entries, $totalRows, $filteredRows, $startIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Used with AJAX in the list view (datatables) to show extra information about that row that didn't fit in the table.
     * It defaults to showing some dummy text.
     *
     * It's enabled by:
     * - setting: $crud->details_row = true;
     * - adding the details route for the entity; ex: Route::get('page/{id}/details', 'PageCrudController@showDetailsRow');
     * - adding a view with the following name to change what the row actually contains: app/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/details_row.blade.php
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showDetailsRow($id)
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('details_row');
        $this->crud->setOperation('list');

        // get entry ID from Request (makes sure its the last ID for nested resources)
        $id = $this->crud->getCurrentEntryId() ?? $id;

        $this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->getEntry($id);
        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getDetailsRowView(), $this->data);
    }
}


if any thing possible related to remote grouping please also do that by setting groups in grid state received on server side and by making use of that get formatted results into groups with information existed according to expanded or collapsed groups.
